# SQL-- calculated columns using previous row

Tags: sql, teradata, recursive-query

I am trying to write the SQL that would create the following table:

```
_row   ID   ColA               ColB              ColC    Mov_Sum         Mult1 Mult2

 1     X   100                  2                .05     102.5             null  null
 2     X   101                  3                .1      206.6             null  null
 3     Y   a*206.6             b*206.6           .2      206.6*(a+b)+.2       a     b
 4     Y   a*(206.6(a+b)+.2)   b*(206.6(a+b)+.2) .4      (etc...)             a     b
```

When ID = 'X', ColA, ColB, and ColC are known and selected from an existing table. Mov_Sum is calculated using the previous row's Mov_Sum + ColA + Col B + ColC.

When ID = 'Y', ColA, ColB and ColC must be calculated using the previous row's Sum_ABC. the multipliers "a" and "b" are constant when ID = 'Y'.

I'm using Teradata SQL and cannot incorporate Lag/Lead syntax. I have succeeded in calculating Mov_Sum (where ID=X) by creating an intermediary table where I left join the table on itself (where a._row >= b._row), then sum(Mov_Sum) grouping by _row.

I cannot figure out how to incorporate this when ID= Y, because now ColA &ColB are a product of the previous Mov_Sum, and not known values.

I am thinking this may require a recursive query. Any suggestions?

Comment: For SQL Server 2012 you shouldn't need a recursive query.  Just CASE expressions and use of the LAG() analytic window function.  You should edit your question to post some sample data and what you've tried, however.  It's very difficult to construct a query from what you've provided so far.  It'd also be good to see the underlying table's structure.

Comment: Can you show your existing query and where you think you need LAG/LEAD (which are easy to rewrite)? And what's your Teradata release?